# c++, netbeans, --whole-archive

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using netbeans on redhat.  I have a suite of related projects:

1. stand alone `.a` utility library
2. stand alone project specific `.a` library
3. executable that depends on the two `.a` libs and a couple third
   party shared and static libs
4. a `.so` module that depends on the two `.a` libs and a couple third
   party shared and static libs

My goal is that the executable and the module will be easily copied onto target machines here to do the necessary tasks without having to make sure that the associated local and third party libs are installed as well.

The executable builds and seems to work fine.  The `.so` module builds fine but the application that loads it finds undefind references to various things.  I have found advice that says to surround the list of needed libraries with

```
g++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive -llib1 -llib2 ... -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

I *just* discovered that you add this in netbeans by going to `{project} > Properties > Linker > Libraries`; editing the list of libraries; and then, `Add Option` to add the strings.  Then you use the `Up/Down` buttons to position the whole-archive options where you want them.  Cool!

The result of this however is:

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU_1-Linux-x86/myLocalSharedObjectModule.so build/Debug/GNU_1-Linux-x86/myLocalSharedObjectModule.o -L/usr/local/myLibTestDestination -Wl,--whole-archive -lpam -lpcre -lsqlite3 /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a -lmyLib-1 -lmyLib-2 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -shared -fPIC
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(mysys_dtrace.o):(.SUNW_dof+0x0): multiple definition of `__SUNW_dof'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(clientlib_dtrace.o):(.SUNW_dof+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `__SUNW_dof' changed from 4050 in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(clientlib_dtrace.o) to 4274 in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(mysys_dtrace.o)
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(mysys_ssl_dtrace.o):(.SUNW_dof+0x0): multiple definition of `__SUNW_dof'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(clientlib_dtrace.o):(.SUNW_dof+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `__SUNW_dof' changed from 4274 in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(clientlib_dtrace.o) to 3490 in /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(mysys_ssl_dtrace.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure what to do about this.  Is it actually possible to link static (mysql and my libs) and shared (sqlite3, pcre, ...) objects into a shared object?

Comment: It would seem easier to just statically link everything into the executable. It could end up being smaller since there is probably a lot in those libs you don't even need.

Comment: You are correct.  The trickey one is the .SO. it is used by a third party product as a sort-of plugin.

Thinking about this overnight, I think maybe I'll just put copies of the necessary libs in a project related install dir and link to those.  I'll bet there are issues with that.